# Watson Analytics can't connect to local db2

Tags: db2, ibm-watson

I'm trying to add a local DB2 as a Data Connection and I'm getting the following error:

Validation of the connection properties failed and reported an incorrect database, SID, or unauthorized user. CDICO0104E: Invalid database, insufficient permissions, or database unavailable: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.20.4] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, ; or socket output stream. Error location: Reply.fill() - insufficient data (-1). Message: Insufficient data. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001 [DW-PRS] [ISI-*****0d44-****-****-****-d49****c96dc] [UN-*****@****.com] [TS-2016-10-28T21:26:31.595+00:00] [CN-dw-service-***-yp-*****-****-****ca981aa] [TID-JVWLVTNUOD28] [MSGID-CDICO8105E] [UIID-4f4f****-****-****-****-****a579d3e1] [ST-DataClick] Additional information: Message ID: CDICO8105E; HTTP status: 400

However the credentials are definitely the correct ones, I can connect to the DB with them. What could be the reason that Watson Analytics cannot reach the DB?

Comment: Connecting public web application to your local DB2 instance requires opening it (the DB2 instance) to the internet or setting up a Bluemix secure gateway. Which is it? How did you test the connectivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would double-check that the ACL is defined correctly in the secure gateway, as well as check the secure gateway log to verify that it is connecting to your DB2 server.

Comment: Yep the ACL config was incorrect. There were fields that I thought were optional that are acutally mandatory.